# Why do Rust Strings have no Short String Optimizations (SSOs)?

Tags: string, rust

I've looked into the source code for `String`, and found that it's implemented in terms of `Vec`, which has no form of small object optimizations:

```rs
pub struct String {
    vec: Vec<u8>,
}
```

Coming from C++, where every major standard library uses Short String Optimizations (SSOs) for `std::string`, this is *very* surprising.
A lot of use cases of strings involve very short strings, such as:

1. if you're writing a compiler, you'll have strings for keywords and tokens, like `"=="` , `"pub"`, `"delete"`
2. if you're stringifying an enum, all of the constant names are typically short enough to fit into an SSO buffer
3. if you're printing stuff using format strings, the format strings are very rarely so long that they wouldn't fit into SSOs
4. if you're parsing a config file with keys and values, both the keys and values are very short typically, like `setting: enabled`
5. if you're storing regular expressions, those can often fit into SSOs too
6. if you're storing a dictionary, pretty much the entirety of it can be SSO'd, because e.g. English words are fairly short

Given this, what is the rationale for not using any SSOs for the default `String`? Would it be possible to add that feature retroactively? Is there any profiling data to demonstrate whether SSOs are helpful or not?

#### Notes on SSOs in C++

SSOs are done by reusing the memory of the `std::string` container that would otherwise store the pointer, size, and capacity to store:

- the size of the internal string (can be just one byte)
- the string data in the container (usually ~20 bytes max length)

It's also possible that only the capacity is reused, and there is a pointer to inside the string object.
All of this is usually done through a `union`, and would be possible in Rust as well.

Comment: While on topic here, you could consider asking also on https://langdev.stackexchange.com/ which is more specialized for this type of question

Comment: Presumably because being a new language it hasn't been "over-optimized" yet. Does the C++ standard library actually include SSO? I'm not sure that it does. I am assuming SSO is some fixed length buffer the type carries around with it, so assuming you want fast copy behavior, this isn't something you would want.

Comment: How long does it take to account for indirection due to a pointer? Perhaps 100 ns or so? How much data can you copy around a CPU cache in 100ns? What if the buffer isn't used? You're wasting space which will cause increased numbers of cache misses. Assuming my guess about how SSO would be implemented is correct, I am not sure this is really an optimization at all.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant SSO does not use a specific cache (which could be wasted) but reuses the bytes of the structure members (pointer+capacity for example).

Comment: Those are genuine questions by the way. I do not know the answer. To answer the question you would really want to do something like this: Find out exactly how the GNU std lib (or any other implementation) does SSO for strings. Then bench mark this in some test application against your own implementation of a string type which is closely related but doesn't have the optimization. You would have to define some standard set of operations to test, and then run it with different distributions of string lengths. You could write a whole paper on this, probably.

Comment: @prog-fh How many bytes of space is that? 16 ?

Comment: Also it's important to note: Which standard library is being discussed? I assume gnu - but maybe it's Microsoft implementation, or some other.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant I don't remember the details but it's something like 16 or 24 depending on the compiler (clang/gcc). Oh I just found this table [here](https://github.com/elliotgoodrich/SSO-23#comparison).

Comment: @prog-fh Ok - so Rust strings are UTF-8. This might be of relevance? I would guess most Rust language designers expect you to be working with 2 byte characters (UTF-16 ?) rather than ascii. This is one of the "selling points" of Rust. Although if you are working with ascii strings, then you could perhaps store pointer + length + capacity bytes in a Rust string, which would be 24 characters. But you would also have to store a byte for info about what "mode" it is in. CPU alignment is 4 bytes, so you're wasting 31 bits just to store a 1 bit flag...

Comment: Has nothing at all to do with UTF-8. There's a lot of discussion here: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/short-string-optimization/8436/11

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant I've added a brief overview over how SSOs are implemented. The details vary from implementation to implementation, but all standard libraries use this technique, so the question isn't specific to just libstdc++ or MSVC STL.

Comment: @JanSchultke Ok interesting. I didn't know about this - or if I did I have forgotten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSO is not always a win - it optimizes short strings at the expense of long strings. Rust prefers to have consistent performance characteristics, especially in the standard library, and let external crates handle the other cases. This way, users of the standard library are never pessimized, and if needed, they can use external crates and still enjoy the optimizations for their particular use-case.

Moreover, SSO in Rust is potentially more expensive than SSO in C++: although I don't know if standard libraries in C++ actually use this ability, C++ has move constructors - and therefore, can have a pointer to the data whether it is stored in the heap or the stack. This way, accessing the data is branch-free. However, Rust cannot do that, because when the object is moved the pointer to the inline storage would have to be updated - but in Rust moves are always simple memcpys.

Moreover, while Rust could define `String` to have SSO, now this is impossible as [it guarantees the buffer will always be stored on the heap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#representation), and also, [`String::into_bytes()` (that returns `Vec<u8>`) guarantees to not copy the data](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_bytes).

Comment: Not every implementation uses an internal pointer for branchless code: libstdc++ has an internal pointer, but libc++ uses branching in SSOs instead. It's debateable which one is better, since internal pointers save you one branch, but this brunch is predictable, and an internal pointer takes up a lot of space that could have been used for string data (8 bytes, likely).

Comment: @JanSchultke Indeed, the main reason is not SSO is not always better. I specified this reason as a second reason (and I also said I don't know if C++ implementations actually use a pointer).